# How to embed PDF in Web Page, which looks like HTML Form?

Tags: pdf, embed

How to **embed PDF** in **Web Page**, which looks like **HTML Form**?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: Did you try [Googling it](http://goo.gl/ByzTw)?